# Spring Data JPA JpaRepository.save(Iterable..) - no javax.validation? (Annotations at Entity not validated)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, bean-validation

Because of performance issues I changed a for loop from:

```
MyRepo myRepo; //MyRepo extends JpaRepository
for (final CSVRecord record : csvParser) {
    ...
    myRepo.save(myEntity);
}
```

to

```
ArrayList<MyEntity> allMyEntities = new ArrayList<>();
for (final CSVRecord record : csvParser) {
    ...
    allMyEntities.add(myEntity);
}
myRepo.save(allMyEntities);  //save(Iterable<S> entities);
```

So performance was better as expected but my test fails because I expected an exception (ConstraintViolationException) for the entity `@Pattern` validation:

```
@Table
public class MyEntity{
    @Pattern(regexp = 'whatever')
    private String checkMe
}
```

This is the exception I got for single save but not for the list save:
    `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [MyEntity] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ] List of constraint violations:[ ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessag`

**Details**

- Method around the for loop is marked as `@Transactional` (anyway save.(Iterable was faster)
- I didn't use flush or anything else in the single save variant

**Question**

Is there a reason why validation is not done for `save(Iterable)`?

**My current workaround**

Call the validation by hand but this feels wrong:

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<MyEntity>> violations = validator.validate(myEntity);
if (violations.size() > 0) {throw new ConstraintViolationException(violations);}
```

Ok, my time profit is now also smaller but ok, nothing is for free ;-).

- single save variant 13 seconds
- iterable save variant 5 sedonds
- iterable save with single validation 8 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have annotations on `Iterable` so validation will not check what is under.

Same as:

```
class Person {

    Child child;

}

class Child {

    @Max(18)
    Integer age;

}
```

If you will validate from `Person` side, it will not validate `Child` classes unless you will annotate your `child` field with `@Valid`.

`Iterable` has no `javax.validation`  annotation, so it's fields are not validated.

But if you do it in one transaction it shouldn't be a problem that you save it one by one with validation. You can also validate before save.

Comment: Thanks. Ok so I have to go with my workaround and single validation for every bean. With `@Valid` I would have to wrap all in new object first.